# Why can I not create a temporary file using a dynamically allocated string?

Tags: c, linux, mkstemp

I am trying to create a directory with log entries with `mkstemp`. But, to my understanding I mustn't pass a string constant to `mkstemp`. I allocate memory for the string and use `snprintf` to format the output which I thought was going to work but `mkstemp` returns a negative value setting errno to EINVAL.

However, in the linux [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) for `mkstemp` it clearly says:

> EINVAL For mkstemp() and mkostemp(): The last six characters of
>     template were not XXXXXX; now template is unchanged.

Furhtermore `mkstemp` never modifies my dynamic string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LOG_DIR "/tmp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *fname;
  FILE *fp;

  if(argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <msg> <severity>\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s/log_entry.XXXXXX", LOG_DIR); // snprintf returns the required length for my string
  if(length < 0) {
    perror("snprintf failed");
    return 1;
  }
  fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * length); // allocate memory for fname based on the return value of snprintf
  snprintf(fname, length, "%s/log_entry.XXXXXX", LOG_DIR); // send formatted output into fname

  int fd = mkstemp(fname); // this returns -1 and errno is set to 22
  if(fd < 0) {
    perror("failed to create entry file");
    return 1;
  }
  fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    perror("failed to open entry file");
    return 1;
  }
  fprintf(fp, "\"%s\" %d ",argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
  fflush(fp);
  fclose(fp);
  free(fname);
  return 0;
}
```

This snippet spits out an error on both of my Linux machines however if I remove the dynamic allocated string and explicitly set `fname` it works

```
char fname[] = "/tmp/log_entry.XXXXXX";
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to allocate the null-terminating character! Also, I recommend using `asprintf` for your usage case. It's one call rather than two.

Comment: @Noldorin `fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * length + 1);` doesn't work if that's what you mean.

Comment: Add `1` where you set the `length` variable. That should do the job. If not, what does `snprintf` return?

Comment: @Noldorin `fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * length+1);
  snprintf(fname, length+1, "%s/log_entry.XXXXXX", LOG_DIR);` still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Linus What error ? Post it .

Comment: Right, tell us the error! The return value of `snprintf` and what `perror` outputs.

Comment: @ameyCU Never mind, it works now for some reason. A follow up question, why does `snprintf(fname, length+1, "%s/log_entry.XXXXXX", LOG_DIR);` still work? If I don't add one to malloc?

Comment: Also, it logically makes sense to put the brackets around (length + 1) even though it probably won't make a difference on your system, since `sizeof (char)` is probably `1.

Comment: @Linus Compiler wont stop you to access invalid memory , if you are lucky you get seg fault . But still that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Linus Because you're getting lucky, and the character after the malloc'd block happens to be readable, and starts with a `0`. Don't do it though, it's unsafe.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I swear I tried adding one to malloc before, but I must've forgot to add one to `snprntf`.

Comment: Sure. But like I said, save yourself all this headache and just use `asprintf`. ;)

Comment: @Noldorin Right, I'm looking into it right now. Sounds useful :)

Comment: @Linus http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html

Comment: Just to note that `asprintf` is neither C standard nor does it appear to be POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
```

should be:

```
fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
```

Now

```
snprintf(fname, length+1, "%s/log_entry.XXXXXX", LOG_DIR);
```

will create the filename. In your version, the filename did not end with 6 'X's which made `mkstemp` fail.

Comment: Also: in OP's version, there was a NUL termnator but only 5 Xs. snprintf truncates to allow space for the terminator.

Comment: @rici, fixed your first comment. From VC2013 documentation: "_If len = count, then len characters are stored in buffer, no null-terminator is appended, and len is returned._" so no null would be appended.

Comment: MSVC is not Posix, of course, but the deviations are disappointing. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html "Otherwise, output bytes beyond the n-1st shall be discarded instead of being written to the array, and a null byte is written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array."

Comment: Since OP specifically refers to Linux, we can assume the Posix-compliant glibc implementation, which null-terminates unless size is 0. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html

Comment: And finally, the sentence you quote is for `_snprintf`. As of 2015, the MS CRT finally supports C99 `snprintf`, apparently correctly. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/10/the-great-crt-refactoring.aspx?PageIndex=2 search for the comment about the snprintf variants

Comment: @rici, that s a great improvement in C99. Thanks for pointing it out to me. Then, in the OP's case, the file would be created, only wth a different name. But the file wasn't created, probably beause it had invalid characters in it (`errno` 22 = `EINVAL`), which can only be explained by no `\0` with invalid characters in the memory following the allocated memory. What's your opinion?

Comment: My opinion is that the filename created by snprintf ended with 5 Xs. The documentation for mkstemp clearly states that EINVAL will be returned if the filename does not end with six Xs.

Comment: @rici, thanks. Solid explanation. I updated the solution with this info.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
```

You fill it completely , leave no space for `'\0'` . :eave a space for null terminator -

```
 fname = malloc(sizeof(char) *(length+1));
```

Then increase length in `snprintf` also to `length+1` .

Comment: @rici You are correct . But won't matter here . I will enclose it in bracket :-)